# After cloning Git repository how do I avoid having to add to system path

Tags: python, git

I cloned a Git repository on my local machine, but in order to to run scripts with imports within the repository I need to append to `sys.path` How can I avoid doing this?

Comment: In general, no changes to the PATH are necessary to run a file downloaded as part of a git repo.  Typically, you just run `python name_of_file.py`.  If you provide the command you are trying to use and the full error message, you are much more likely to get a tailored answer to your issue.

Comment: @FiddleStix The question is not about `$PATH` but about Python's `sys.path` — a path for imports.

Comment: The question is too generic. The best thing is to create a Python virtualenv and install all modules and packages into it. Or you can set `PYTHOPATH` environment variable which is reflected in Python's `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Git repository has a proper `setup.py`, you can install it in your virtualenv (or similar – whatever you do, you don't want to mess up your global packages with this) with

```py
pip install -e ./whereveryouclonedit
```

– the `-e` makes sure Pip only creates "links" to `whereveryouclonedit`, so you can hack at the downloaded package.

If the Git repository does *not* have a proper `setup.py`, you will have to resort to messing with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`; at that point it'd be better to just write the `setup.py`.